# How to rock a chair on a plane

Tags: 3d-view

Good Evening.

I'm trying to rock this Chair back and forth on a plane, but I'm not getting a hang of it. [image]

From what I have attempted to do, the result, is the chair rotating/spinning round a spot/the X-axis.

I need to rock the chair first before I start adding the key frames and extras, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: A rigidbody sim should be able to do this

Comment: Edit: oh ok the chair needs to move, I would do it manually and visually but there must be an intelligent way

Comment: @AllenSimpson -- I think I followed your approach in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be a smart way to do it but here is the dumb manual way:

Put the origin at the rotation center. Create a first keyframe at the default position:

[image]

Move the player along the timeline, move the chair and rotate it, create a second keyframe:

[image]

The third keyframe is a copy of the first one, the fourth is a negative copy of the second (here I just put minus before the location on X and minus before the rotation on Y):

[image]

It still needs a bit of tweakings in the *Graph Editor* so that it doesn't slide:

[image]

Comment: I think the "smart way to do it" would be [Robin Betts' approach](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/268937/2952) - which is also very helpful to know. Still, I think your method is very practical and easy to implement for the average user.

Comment: Thanks, i knew Robin would be here for the smart solution  ;)

Answer (score 3):

per @AllenSimpson here is the Rigid body simulation approach.   I used a combination of a short puff of air (Force) to start a rocking motion, followed by a single hit of an (invisible) cube to have another rocking motion.

[image]

To continue the rocking motion --for either of these methods -- one could add either a cycles or a sine function F-Curve modifier so that the force will be applied again and again (in cycles).

[image]

The upside to this approach might be that you get a bit more variation around the rocking motion.   The downside is the dual: you may want a constant rocking motion, as in some ghost movie. Also it would be possible to apply cycles and noise modifiers to @moonboots solution, so get similar variations.

Answer (score 3):

Rockin' is Rollin'. Just not by very much, and in a straight line.

For any angle the chair rotates, in order not to slide, it must move by the arc-length swept out by angle of rotation. Since there are `2*pi` radians to a circle, if the angle `theta` is measured in radians, then the distance moved must be `theta`  * `r` (the radius of the circle of which your rocker is a segment). So a driver is easy to set up:

For convenience, put the chair's origin at the center of the circle of which the rocker is an arc.

- You can parent your chair to a 'Root' Empty, so you can move and rotate the whole rig  without screwing things up.
- Then you can set things up to, say, rotate the chair about its Y while moving it in its X
- Right-click in the chair's Rotation > Y field, and 'Copy as New Driver'
- Right-click in the chair's Translation > X field, and 'Paste Driver'
- Right-click again on the driven field, and 'Edit Driver'.
- Change the driver to a scripted expression, and set the expression to multiply the provided Y-rotation variable by the radius of your rocker.

[image]

Then you can move the chair about using the Root Empty, and rock the chair by rotating it in Y.